# Get gene name and molecular function from gene ontology using Wikidata

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am trying to get gene name, molecular function for each gene but I am getting an error:

> Query time out reached limit

This is the current query I have:

```
SELECT ?geneLabel ?molecular_functionLabel WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
  OPTIONAL { ?gene wdt:P680 ?molecular_function. }
  ?gene wdt:P31 wd:Q7187.
}
```

However, when adding `LIMIT` to the end I receive results:

```
SELECT ?geneLabel ?molecular_functionLabel WHERE {
      SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
      OPTIONAL { ?gene wdt:P680 ?molecular_function. }
      ?gene wdt:P31 wd:Q7187.
}

LIMIT 100
```

My question is what could be  I am doing wrong?  or should this be filtered by the protein domain e.g. filter by ketoreductase to avoid receiving results that reach the limit?
And how can I combine two ontologies such as gene ontology and chromosome ontology?

ketoreductase ontology id: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q62989273

Comment: what do you mean by "wrong"? There is nothing wrong (ok, I would put the OPTIONAL pattern after the other, but that's all) - the main reason is that you're using a shared public service and it might be busy now.

Comment: @UninformedUser ah ok so nothing wrong with the query, but how can I get that to be filtered by protein e.g. filter by ketoreductase?

Comment: @UninformedUser is there a way to optimize my query?

Comment: what mean filter? your query query gets "all genes with its molecular functions" - so, how is a protein connected to those genes in Wikidata? If you know this, just add the triple pettern(s)

Comment: with "ontology" you most likely mean "classes" or "types" - what "combine" means I don`t know? If you mean everything that is either a gene or chromosome, then you can use `UNION` or nowadays even better `VALUES`: `SELECT ?itemLabel ?molecular_functionLabel WHERE {
 
  VALUES ?type {wd:Q7187 wdt:P1057}
  ?item wdt:P31 ?type.
  OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P680 ?molecular_function. }
   SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
  
}`

Comment: there is no room for optimization - I mean, it's a simple triple pattern with a single OPTIONAL to get additional data. It's just that the endpoint is busy or slow now - for whatever reason. But I'm sure, if you remove the `SERVICE`, it will be much faster.

Comment: for example, my query without the SERVICE stuff to get labels will work and return 1195353 results. But I assume you need labels.

Comment: by the way, what's the use case for this data? I mean, if you're also trying to get COVID-19 KAggel challenge data stuff, there are other medical ontologies online and free for download